# I want to Validate Radio Button List in asp.net using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to Validate Radio Button List in asp.net using jquery, where I am having radio button list in child page, and I need to show alert box when user never selects any option

Here is the code, which I have tried.

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>").click(function(){
          var v=$("#<%=rdTax.ClientID %>input:checked").val(); 
     }); 
});
```

Comment: show some code ,what have you tried?

Comment: I tried above code but i could not find it...

Comment: Do you have space between `%>` and `input:checked` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should like this

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>").click(function(){
          var v=$("#<%=rdTax.ClientID %> input:checked").length;
          if(v==0)
             alert('Not checked any radio button');
     }); 
});
```

or better you can try this

```
$(function(){ 
    $("[id$=btnSave]").click(function(){
          var v=$("[id$=rdTax]").find("input:checked").length;
          if(v==0)
             alert('Not checked any radio button');
     }); 
});
```

Comment: @PramodSawant  mark answer as correct answer if it's working for you

Answer (score 1):

Use **length** to check if any radiobutton is checked ,length would be zero if no button is selected

```
$('input[type=radio][name=radiobuttonlistID]:checked').length
```

and use **prop** to check or uncheck them

```
$('input[type=radio][name="radiobuttonlistID"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to validate a radio button set the default selection of radio button when you want. I think this is a best way to validate radio button.

If you want to use jquery validation plugin see a link:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html